# How can I backup and restore my Windows 2003 Firewall Settings?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, firewall, windows-firewall

It seems that when I install TFS I just lost all my Windows Firewall settings.

How can I back this up and restore them on Windows 2003?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The firewall configuration is stored in the registry

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\StandardProfile\
```

It can be exported to backup or if you do a registry backup its included in it.

Answer (score 1):

Since Windows Vista/Windows Server 2008 netsh.exe utility allows (netsh advfirewall export)  to export/import Windows Firewall with Advanced security configuration.

But it seems for Windows XP/Windows Server 2003 no other possible [standard] solutions for this task except export/import registry settings as jer.salamon stated above.